# Random intercept only for 1 subgroup in lmer

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

suppose I have a case study with 3 different populations, A, B and C. For all groups I have data on, e.g. body mass, length and sex of a given species. For group A I also have information on the year of birth, which I may be interested to include in the analysis as a random term to account for the cohort effect, while for groups B and C I have no such information. The dataframe would look something like:

```
Pop   Coh   Weight  Length  Sex
A     2010  12.1    34      m
A     2011  13.4    42      m
A     2012  10.3    36      f
A     2010  10.5    32      m
A     2013  12.1    37      f
A     2014  12.4    35      f
A     2011  14.1    32      f
...
B     NA    13.1    36      m
B     NA    10.5    35      f
B     NA    12.4    32      f
B     NA    12.6    35      m
...
C     NA    13.7    31      m
C     NA    11.5    37      f
C     NA    10.7    33      m
C     NA    11.9    35      f
...
```

Let's now suppose I want to investigate the relationship between Weight and Length, for males and females of different populations, e.g. by using a 3-way interaction.  Would it still be possible to run the analysis in one single mixed model with a random intercept (cohort) only for group A?

With my actual dataset, the model

```
lmer(Weight ~ Length * Sex * Pop + (1 + Pop | Coh) )
```

fitted changing NAs to 1 appears to work, as it returns the same estimates for population B and C (but clearly not A) as the model

```
lm(Weight ~ Length * Sex * Pop)
```

but I am not quite sure if this is the correct approach.

Thanks,

Luca

Comment: Did you mean 1  + Coh | Pop?

Comment: I actually meant (1 + Pop | Coh): the idea was to fit a random intercept shared by individuals that have the same value for Cohort, and allow a random slope for different Populations. This makes biological sense, as the factor Cohort is meaningful only within different levels of Population. This syntax should also include a correlation between the two random effects, is this correct?

Comment: I think it is not doing what you hope but I think I will leave this one for the real experts in mixed effects models. If they do not turn up to answer your question you could try the R-SIG-mixed-models mailing list (and mention you failed to get a response here).